# Updating an XML column type from the value from a joined table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have to update a value in my XML column:

```
UPDATE HR_XML
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
                     (/Salaries/Marketing/Employee[@ID=("2")]/Salary/text())[1] 
                     with ("60000")')
```

Currently the value `60000` is hard coded, but I am going to inner join with another table.

How can I use the value that comes from another table?

```
UPDATE h
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
                     (/Salaries/Marketing/Employee[@ID=("2")]/Salary/text())[1] 
                     with ("60000")')
FROM HR_XML h
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON h.id = t2.id
```

The value is from the joined tables column `t2.NewSalary`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sql:column()` XQuery function for this:

```
UPDATE h
SET Salaries.modify('replace value of 
                     (/Salaries/Marketing/Employee[@ID=("2")]/Salary/text())[1] 
                     with sql:column("t2.NewSalary")') -- table.column
FROM HR_XML h
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON h.id = t2.id
```

See [more details on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-column?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, as we don't have an sample XML, or other data, but should be more than enough to get you on the right path:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE XMLTable (id int, SomeXML xml);

INSERT INTO XMLTable
VALUES(1,
'<Root>
    <Element>
        <Item>Cheese</Item>
    </Element>
</Root>');

GO
CREATE TABLE ValueTable (id int, SomeValue varchar(20));

INSERT INTO ValueTable
VALUES(1, 'Bacon');

GO

UPDATE X
SET SomeXML.modify('replace value of 
                    (/Root/Element/Item/text())[1] 
                    with sql:column("V.SomeValue")')
FROM XMLTable X
     JOIN ValueTable V ON X.id = V.id;

SELECT *
FROM XMLTable;

GO
DROP TABLE XMLTable;
DROP TABLE ValueTable;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43ef39703b0074b49b01921b2cf1cf0e)